# How to select and get dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code is

```
<select class="form_input_select bx-def-font" name="Sex[0]">
     <option value="Male">Man</option>                 
  <option value="Female">Woman</option>                   
<option value="Other" selected="selected">_Other</option>
    </select>
```

I am using below Selenium Java code:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]")));
select.selectByIndex(0);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Cursor move on Man , But Man is not Show , Show only _Others

Please help me for solve my issues I have applied more and more syntax but but I am not success to show Man...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `getText()` to get selected text.

```
Select se=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]")));
WebElement option = se.getFirstSelectedOption();
String gender=option.getText;
```

or use one of following options

```
se.selectByVisibleText("Man");
se.selectByIndex(0);
se.selectByValue("Male");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :-

```
se.selectByValue("Male");
```

OR

```
se.selectByVisibleText("Man");
```

OR

Use javascriptexecutor

Answer (score 0):

Hi think before selecting any option from the drop down please make all the options visible in the DOM so do it like below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("path to drop down upon click it will show 
the dd with values")).click();
```

Now once the options are visible on the page use the way you select an option form the DD

```
Select se=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]")));
se.selectByIndex(0);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]")).sendKeys("Man");

Finally i have found Solution 
Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 0):

To select any option from dropdown we have to click the dropdown element and select the desired option. Please find the below sample code:

```
WebElement gender = driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]"));
gender.click();
Select selectGender = new Select(gender);
selectGender.selectByValue("Male");
// or
// you can use any of below functions of Select class
selectGender.selectByIndex(0);
// or
selectGender.selectByVisibleText("Male");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Code for Selecting the Values from Dropdown.

We have created the anonymous abject for `Select`.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mainOrderForm:orderType"))).selectByVisibleText("Factory Order");

                        OR

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mainOrderForm:orderType"))).selectByIndex(Index_No.);

                        OR

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mainOrderForm:orderType"))).selectByValue("Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. Just try atleast whether the selected option is getting printed on the console

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Sex[0]")));
    select.selectByIndex(0);
    
    WebElement element = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println(element.getText());
                  or
    select.selectByVisibleText("Man");
```