# How to select the drop down value in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am not able to select the value in drop down in above mentioned code,

```
 public class Dropdown {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "I:/shopclues/demoqa/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://demoqa.com/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.findElementByLinkText("Registration").click();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          WebElement country = driver.findElementByXPath("//select[@id='dropdown_7']");
          Select dropdown = new Select(country);
          List<WebElement> options = dropdown.getOptions();
          for (WebElement option1 : options) 
          {
              System.out.println(option1.getText());
              if(option1.getText().startsWith("india"))
              {
                  option1.click();
                  break;
              }

          }
     }

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on [gihan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977072/how-to-select-and-get-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-by-using-java), you can select via the following:

dropdown .selectByVisibleText("India");
   dropdown.selectByIndex(0);       dropdown.selectByValue("India");

For your purposes, the first option should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following way to select a dropdown -

```
    WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown_7"));
    Select dropdown = new Select(country);

    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("india");  // pass the text which is visible on site

    //or
    dropdown.selectByIndex(1); // pass the index of dropdown value you want to select

    //or
    dropdown.selectByValue("your_value");
```

Or change your code

```
WebElement country = driver.findElementByXPath("//select[@id='dropdown_7']");
```

to

```
WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown_7"));
```

Comment: thanks bro now its working, but i want to know why for each is not working?

Comment: try printing the value of `option1` in `For Each` loop and you would see the issue.

Comment: you can do so but i think there is problem in your xpath - `WebElement country = driver.findElementByXPath("//select[@id='dropdown_7']");` I haven't seen method `findElementByXPath` in java

Comment: Its in selenium remote webdriver.